# elastic apm span and opentelemetry span not linked

Tags: open-telemetry, elastic-apm

I installed below ElasticStack.

Kibana Version: 7.17.9
ElasticSearch Version: 7.17.9
Elastic-apm server version: 7.17.9

All are running locally

I have a server1 calling another server2, both are written using spring boot, but they use different apm agent.
For the server1, it uses opentelemetry-javaagent-2.jar and exporter connects to local elastic-apm server at http://localhost:8200
For server 2, it uses elastic-apm-agent-1.4.0.jar and exporter also connects to local http://localhost:8200.

But after a HTTP API call into server1 (which calls server2 internally), the trace for each server is not connected. I can view them in each traces tab in Kibana, but not from server1 API traces (which should contain the traces when it calls servers).

Thanks!

I did some check, seems the opentelemetry agent adds "traceparent" when it calls server2, which is standard W3C propagator header.
But for elastic-apm-agent, it will add "elastic-apm-traceparent" header.
Is there any way to connect the trace together when I use opentelemetry agent and elastic-apm agent together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All recent Elastic APM agents [use the standard w3c traceparent header](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elastic-apm-adopts-w3c-tracecontext) - version 1.4.0 of the java agent [predates the standard](https://www.w3.org/blog/news/archives/8298). Upgrade to a [newer release](https://github.com/elastic/apm-agent-java/releases), currently v1.38.0, to resolve this issue.